# Trouble With Not Being Able to NOT Make Bullets Appear

Tags: css, feedburner

I apologize for having to ask such a basic question but I'm really stumped and any help would be most appreciated.

On this page; http://www.your-adrenaline-fix.com/Motocross-blog.html I have a Feedburner feed which displays the  and meta descrip of recently added pages but with the following css

```
#MotocrossBlog {
    list-style-type:none !important;
    border:1px solid #000;
    padding:15px;
    margin:10px;
    background: #F9FFFF;
    box-shadow:4px 6px 7px #888888;
}


div.feedburnerFeedBlock ul { 
list-style-type: none 
}
```

I am STILL Unable to prevent the bullets from displaying.

I have also thoroughly reviewed the following help article but nothing seems to work.
https://support.google.com/feedburner/answer/78974?hl=en

I thank you guys in advance,

Stuart K

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `list-style-type: none;` on `li` not on `ul`.

**Correct CSS:**

```
div.feedburnerFeedBlock ul { 
    list-style-type: none 
}
```

Comment: But I already have that. (copied from Google's help article and placed just below the block I created) yet it still wont work

Answer (score 0):

```
.feedburnerFeedBlock li { 
list-style: none 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ul` has class CircleBullet which override your CSS.

Instead of setting list style on the div -> ul, set it dirrectly to your CircleBullet class

Comment: You may not believe it but I have written this entire site but I CANNOT get my head around this. @C. Malet, Could you please elaborate?

Comment: In  your css file (support-files/style.css) you've this : `.CircleBullet {margin-left: 20px;list-style:disc;}`. Replace it by `.CircleBullet {margin-left: 20px;list-style:none;}`

Answer (score 0):

Try to override their CSS by incorporating it in your stylesheet.

**For Instance,**

```
#ContentColumn ul{list-style-type:none;}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks SO Much for this @Nathan Lee!! (All I had to do was add ul to the block I created. HooRah!! BTW, The feedburner example: div.feedburnerFeedBlock ul had my head spinning. I'll be thoroughly investigating this so as to better understand what's going on but I thank you all for your help.